# How do I load entities with Null values?

Tags: entities

The following fails with an exception.

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('foo_module_division')->loadByProperties(['enabled'=>TRUE, 'parent_code'=> NULL]).
```

How else do I specify I want to load entities whose *parent_code* field is `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is the result of how [`EntityStorageBase::loadByProperties()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x) builds the underlying `WHERE` clause; it's utilizing [`::buildPropertyQuery()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AbuildPropertyQuery/8.2.x) which casts `NULL` to an array then uses the `IN` operator to compare; this won't work since you need a `IS NULL` query to find `NULL` entries in the DB.

Instead, you can build your own entity storage query in a similar way as `loadByProperties()`:

```
$es = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('foo_module_division')
$q = $es->getQuery();
$results = $q->condition('parent_code', NULL, 'IS')->condition('enabled', TRUE)->execute();
return $results ? $es->loadMultiple($results) : array();
```

Comment: Many thanks Shawn. Works great for me. Thanks for the detailed explanations - would probably have never known main cause for error

Comment: For anybody who stumbles across this on Drupal 9 or 10, the condition for `IS NULL` is now written like so; `condition('parent_code', '', 'IS NULL')`

Answer (score 2):

The example of getting articles that has empty body:

```
  $entityStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = $entityStorage->getQuery();
  $query->condition('type', 'article');
  $query->notExists('body');
  $nids = $query->execute();
  $nodes = $entityStorage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

Comment: notExists works, it's documented here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditions#s-using-is-null-is-not-null-exists-and-not-exists